# Image from stream, function or directly, what is fastest?

Tags: image, arrays

Probably a wasted question, but better to ask than just guessing.

If i want to turn my array back to an image, what is faster.

```
Image myimage = byteArrayToImage(myarray);

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

or

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(myarray);
Image myimage = Image.GetFromStream(ms);
```

As both are doing the same thing, i guess they are at the same speed.
But i am wondering if using a function will slow it down as it must return the variable, and such.

Comment: Compared to the image processing itself the function call overhead will be insignificant, but I can't see any reason not to use `GetFromStream()` here as it's already provided. Why write your own?

Comment: Well it´s just that i took it from one that had both (to array and to image). But i will go with using the other method and skip the function as it does the same thing.